# Last six months list in PHP

Tags: php

I need the previous six months list and am using the following code for that.

```
for ($i=6; $i >= 1; $i--) {
  array_push($months, date('M', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month')));
}

print_r($months);
```

Its gives the wrong output as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Dec'
    [1] => 'Dec'
    [2] => 'Jan'
    [3] => 'Mar'
    [4] => 'Mar'
    [5] => 'May'
)
```

It must be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Nov'
    [1] => 'Dec'
    [2] => 'Jan'
    [3] => 'Feb'
    [4] => 'Mar'
    [5] => 'Apr'
)
```

Where am i wrong. Help please

Comment: The problem is that 'month' isn't defined as you think it is. It being the 31st and all. So the 31st of the 5th month minus 1 month is the 31st of the 4th month. Which is the first of the fith month obviously.

Comment: @Nanne you should probably put that as an answer, great explanation :)

Comment: @siganteng thanks, but I didn't have time to acutally test something usefull as a solution, so it's only half what smk3108 needs :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to start the calculation from the first day of the month.

```
$first  = strtotime('first day this month');
$months = array();

for ($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i--) {
  array_push($months, date('M', strtotime("-$i month", $first)));
}

print_r($months);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Nov
    [1] => Dec
    [2] => Jan
    [3] => Feb
    [4] => Mar
    [5] => Apr
)

*/
```

Comment: the output is not as OP wanted.

Comment: $first  = strtotime('first day previous month');
$months = array();

for ($i = 6; $i <= 1; $i--) {
  array_push($months, date('M', strtotime("-$i month", $first)));
} works fine with one change.

Answer (score 4):

And as always I am posting the object way of doing this:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of this month - 6 months');
$endDate   = new DateTime('last month');
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1M'); // P1M => 1 month per iteration

$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);

foreach($datePeriod as $dt) {
  array_push($months, $dt->format('M'));
}

/* output:
Array
(
   [0] => Nov
   [1] => Dec
   [2] => Jan
   [3] => Feb
   [4] => Mar
   [5] => Apr
)
*/
```

See [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime), [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) and [DatePeriod](http://php.net/dateperiod) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
date('M',strtotime('-'.$i.' Month', strtotime(date('Y-m-01'))))
```

why: because today is the 31st of May and not evry month has 31 days.
actualy this (i mean +/- month) function is not so reliable. can you guess what is the utput of this one:

```
print(date('Y-M-d',strtotime('+1 Month', strtotime(date('2012-01-30'))))."\n");
```

?